# Why I can not get the jsp thought its path?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I use struts in my Java EE project:

In my `loading.jsp` if I use the below `src`, I will get `404` error:

```
<IFRAME src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/page/menu/alermDevice.jsp" name="dev" id="dev" frameBorder="0" width="500" scrolling="auto" height="400">
</IFRAME>
```

[image]

But if I use below src:

```
<IFRAME src="elecMenuAction_alermDevice.do" name="dev" id="dev" frameBorder="0" width="500" scrolling="auto" height="400">
</IFRAME>
```

I will get the correct information.

This is my `struts.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"></constant>
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"></constant>
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do"></constant>

    <package name="system" namespace="/system" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="elecTextAction_*" class="elecTextAction" method="{1}">
            <result name="save">/system/textAdd.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="elecMenuAction_*" class="elecMenuAction" method="{1}">
            <result name="menuHome">/WEB-INF/page/menu/home.jsp</result>
            <result name="title">/WEB-INF/page/menu/title.jsp</result>
            <result name="left">/WEB-INF/page/menu/left.jsp</result>
            <result name="change">/WEB-INF/page/menu/change.jsp</result>
            <result name="loading">/WEB-INF/page/menu/loading.jsp</result>
            <result name="logout" type="redirect">index.jsp</result>
            <result name="alermStation">/WEB-INF/page/menu/alermStation.jsp</result>
            <result name="alermDevice">/WEB-INF/page/menu/alermDevice.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Why I use the path can not access the JSP? only use the action I can get it yet?

Comment: Since you're using struts why do you want to call the jsp directly instead of an action that delivers the jsp?

Comment: If is that if I use the struts, I will only use the action to deliver the jsp? can not use the path to access it?

Comment: Resources under WEB-INF are not public so when the **browser** attempts to fetch the resource it cannot find it.

Comment: You probably could directly access jsps provided that they're not in `WEB-INF` since any files in there are considered private, i.e. are not directly exposed  to the client. The main question still would be: would you really want to do that? You'd might need quite some additional configuration to make it work, so would it be worth the effort?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I think I understand it now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server cannot get resources from and below `WEB-INF` folder. When action is invoked it returns a response as an execution of the result. It's used a result type `dispatcher` which is used by default to forward request to the specified URL (the requested JSP page).

> #### [Dispatcher Result](https://struts.apache.org/docs/dispatcher-result.html)
>
> Includes or forwards to a view (usually a jsp). Behind the scenes
>   Struts will use a `RequestDispatcher`, where the target servlet/JSP
>   receives the same request/response objects as the original
>   servlet/JSP. Therefore, you can pass data between them using
>   `request.setAttribute()` - the Struts action is available.
>
> There are three possible ways the result can be executed:
>
> - If we are in the scope of a JSP (a `PageContext` is available), `PageContext`'s `PageContext#include(String)` method is
>     called.
> - If there is no `PageContext` and we're not in any sort of include (there is no `"javax.servlet.include.servlet_path"` in the request
>     attributes), then a call to 
>     `RequestDispatcher#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,
>     javax.servlet.ServletResponse)`  is made.
> - Otherwise, `RequestDispatcher#include(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,
>     javax.servlet.ServletResponse)` is called.

---

When servlet dispatcher is invoked it has not such restriction and can return resource with the same response that was originally requested.